# Fingerprint reader not detected after suspend

Tags: usb, suspend, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a Thinkpad P14s with a fingerprint detector, which works fine at boot using fprintd. `lsusb` reports it as

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.
```

The problem is that after the laptop is suspended, the line above is not present in `lsusb` and the fingerprint reader is not detected and visible to `fprintd`.

In the BIOS I have changed the sleep mode to `linux` as it would not work with the default `windows` at all. I have updated the bios and and fingerprint firmware using `fwupdmgr` and also the latest version of the kernel, 5.17.

I have also tried to add the following kernel startup arguments

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

None of that worked.

Some relevant info

```
uname -a
Linux zah-ThinkPad-P14s-Gen-2a 5.17.0-051700-generic #202203202130 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 20 21:33:41 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Bios info

```
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Summary:            UEFI ESRT device
│ │   Current version:    0.1.14
│ │   Vendor:             Lenovo (DMI:LENOVO)
│ │   Update State:       Success
```

Fingerprint reader info

```
├─Prometheus:
│ │   Summary:            Fingerprint reader
│ │   Current version:    10.01.3478575
│ │   Vendor:             Synaptics (USB:0x06CB)
│ │   Install Duration:   2 seconds
│ │   Device Flags:       • Updatable
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
```

I am using Linux Mint 20.3 which should be similar enough to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hello. I see a kernel version in your question but I do not see a version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the question to add that information.

Comment: Same issue on Thinkpad T14 Gen 2 AMD running ArchLinux with kernel 5.17.5-zen1-1-zen, same synaptics firmware 10.01.3478575 as OP, and BIOS ver 1.14.

Comment: @JinnKo do you have an opportunity to test this with Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved after installing the latest firmware updates (as of June 2022).

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

which leaves the system firmware at version 0.1.17 and installs something called `Prometheus IOTA Config`.